# node.js imap not connection to ionos

Tags: node.js, imap, node.js-connect

I am using the "imap" package for connection to ionos server

```
const imap = new Imap({
        user: 'xxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxx',
        host: 'imap.ionos.com',
        port: 993,
        tls: true
});
...
imap.connect();
```

But I always get back this error, which is not really much.

```
Error: authentication failed
    at Connection._resTagged (/usr/src/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1502:11)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:194:10)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Parser.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Parser._resTagged (/usr/src/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:175:10)
    at Parser._parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:139:16)
    at Parser._tryread (/usr/src/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:82:15)
    at TLSSocket.Parser._cbReadable (/usr/src/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:53:12)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12) {
  type: 'no',
  textCode: undefined,
  source: 'authentication'
}
```

I tried with the port 465 and 587 aswell and set tlsOptions rejectUnauthorized to false, but no effect. Same issue occurs on gmail.
Anyone has ever experienced this?

Comment: I don't know this package, but it seems simply your authentication was rejected.  Have you tried running an IMAP client (like thunderbird) on the same host to see if you can log in?

Comment: hi, imap is the most common package for a imap-client. Yes other clients like thunderbird are working. It has to do with node or openssl underlying :(